# Unicode characters not displaying properly in the Visual Studio Code's integrated terminal

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code

Coding in C# in Visual Studio Code, when using the Unicode characters \u00B2 and \u00F7 they display as ┬▓ ├À in the integrated terminal for Visual Studio Code - does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: What OS do you run it on?

Answer (score -1):

Just change the Console encoding and it will be fine.

```
Console.OutputEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode
```